# PHP Link generator - design path

Tags: php, web

I'm building a website in which the download link for files will be generated at runtime by connecting to a database and getting the current download link from there.

I was wondering whats the best design path i should take to implement it.

What i have in mind so far, is having a linker.php file which i'll include in all pages of the site (Where there's a download link), and in this file i'll auto-fill a `$downloadLink` variable and just use     `<?php echo $downloadLink; ?>` wherever i need to use that download link.

Is this the right way to go?

Should I just have the linker.php file auto-execute?

Comment: show is what you have done. give us your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what your db structure is like but. It would probably be helpful to to have in the linker.php file a function that you could pass a variable like:

```
<?php
function get_downloadlink_byid( $id ){
   code....
}
?>
```

And on your page you could have

```
<?php echo get_downloadlink_byid('999'); ?>
```

This way each page could request different links.